# Copy and Rename jar File in Azure Pipelines

Tags: gradle, azure-devops, build, azure-pipelines, file-rename

I need to rename a jar file (gradle build) from the build/libs folder to the same path. But, I get an error that the syntax is not correct. Could someone help me on this by providing the correct syntax for renaming a jar file and copying to the same folder.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Copy and Rename jar File in Azure Pipelines

You could use powershell inline task to do this:

```
Rename-Item -Path "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\build\libs\myTestApp-1.0-20190819.105207-1.jar" -NewName "NewName.jar"
```

[image]

I think if you rename the file to the same path, you should not need to copy to the same folder.

In case, you need the copy command, you could check the document [Copy-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.1).

And if you are want use other specify syntax to rename the file, please tell me the language you used and the scripts you are using.